# How do I remove these white space characters from Swift Mailer?

Tags: email, swiftmailer

My Swift Mailer code includes a variable being sent in the body. The email sends but doesn't get rid of the white space characters.

The following text: `76a7289eb67f6468356cba907809f2fd Winner :)` gets translated into the following: `933eac234b1bf85619c971c4b3bf90df%20Winner%20%3A%29`

This is my code:

```
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Wonderful Subject')
 ->setContentType("text/html")
  ->setBody((rawurlencode($token. " Winner :)")));
```

I know the email is sending. I haven't included any background information life the sender or receiver. How do I fix this problem?